# In which order is && and || is evaluated in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators

```
if (2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6) printf("OK");
else printf("FAIL");
```

I am confused on how will the computer evaluate this if statement. My guess is (Since && comes before ||):

```
if ((2<3 || 3<4) && 5>6) printf("OK");
else printf("FAIL");
```

Since the statement is wrong the if should print FAIL. But the answer sheet says that the answer is OK.
My question is that when encountered with a situation like this should i evaluate from left to right or start from &&?

Comment: Lookup Opeator Precedence. Operators of equal precedence are evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that if you have to look up operator precedence, add parentheses to remove all doubt.

Comment: `&&` has greater precedence than `||`.

Comment: What,@SteveFriedl said.  Don't write code like this, just don't.  Use brackets and intermediate vars to make it immediately clear what the code does without any intensive deductions and/or  checking precedence lists.  If you insist on writing 'clever' code, you will pay for it at test/debug time.

Answer (score 1):

Test yourself. C does not evaluate all expressions when the result is known
https://godbolt.org/z/dE4y3M , https://godbolt.org/z/E_sxhX

```
#include <stdio.h>

int first(int x)
{
    printf("FIRST\n");
    return x;
}

int second(int x)
{
    printf("SECOND\n");
    return x;
}

int third(int x)
{
    printf("third\n");
    return x;
}

int fourth(int x)
{
    printf("fourth\n");
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    if(first(0) || second(0) && third(1) || fourth(1)) printf("TRUE\n");
    else printf("FALSE\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Logical and (&&) is higher than logical or (||), and is evaluated left to right.

See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm).

```
if (2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6) printf("OK");
else printf("FAIL");
```

Is the same as...

```
if ((2<3) || ((3<4) && (5>6))) printf("OK");
else printf("FAIL");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), you'll see that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`.  It also shows that `<` and `>` have higher precedence than both of them.

This means that this expression:

```
if (2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6)
```

Will be parsed as:

```
if ((2<3) || ((3<4) && (5>6)))
```

So the operands of the highest precedence operators are grouped first followed by the next highest.  When dealing the operators of equal precedence, some group left-to-right while others group right-to-left.

It's good practice however to always use parenthesis around these operators to make it clear to the reader what your intentions are.

Comment: Good practice? Too many parentheses can make code even harder to read, good example are the two code lines right above, first one reads *much* easier than second one...

Comment: @Aconcagua Until someone reads your code that isn't as familiar with the operator precedence rules.

Comment: I don't agree: you shouldn't code assuming it's to be read by a moron. Using too many parentheses can make code harder to read and is occasionally harmful, e.g. `auto bonus = 1e7 * (1/2);`. One of the *only* places I allow them in my code bases is when using ternary conditional operators.

Comment: @dbush So you'd place parentheses around `x = (7 + (10 * 12))` as well (we now *need* the parentheses around the sum because `operator=` *might* have higher precedence!)?

Comment: Hm, while not *fully* agreeing on the parentheses part, it doesn't justify the DV either (in my eyes), rest of the answer is fine...

Comment: @Bathsheba It's not for pebble and mountains, it's for principle ;)

Comment: Parenthesis on `(3<4)` and `(5>6)` are an exageration, but it was an example to hilight the actual behaviour. Of course, extreme use of parenthesis makes difficult to read, but adding some parenthesis DO make things clear for people that, even being experienced in C programming, might want analyze code without using a C manual every three lines. A senior programmer in the company where I was a trainee, 15 years ago, used to say "Parenthesis are free!". ;)

Comment: @Cubo78: For me that's a real shame: when I see `2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6` I automatically group the `3<4 && 5>6` part in my head. If you work with numerical code then you really do need to learn that table.

Comment: @Cubo78 Exactly.  I wouldn't necessarily parenthesize the `<` or `>` comparisons, but for `||` and `&&` I definitely would.  While I know where most of the operators lie in terms of precedence, I still haven't memorized where the logical and bitwise operators sit relative to each other

Comment: @Bathsheba Ok, but in *real life* you will hardly see `2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6`. You will probably see something like `callFunction1( with, a, lot, of, parameters) < some->structure->with->a->lot->of->nested.structs  || callFunction2(try, to, understand,me)<anotherFunctionWithAVeryLongName() && a.function->pointer(analyze, me)>FLAG_A|FLAG_B|A_LOT_OF_OTHER_FLAGS`

Comment: @Cubo78: you and I clearly have different lives and for that I salute you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The logical AND operator has a higher priority than the logical OR operator. So the expression in the if statement

```
if (2<3 || 3<4 && 5>6) printf("OK");
```

is equivalent to the following expression

```
if ( 2<3 || ( 3<4 && 5>6 ) ) printf("OK");
```

The both operators are evaluated left-to-right.

And for the logical OR operator "**If the ﬁrst operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.**" (C Standard)

So as the first operand of the logical OR operator `2 < 3` yields true then the result of the whole expression is not equal to 0 and evaluates as true (its value is the integer 1).